# What is the right way to do Data Binding for input control in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a form which accepts x-axis and y-axis values to create a chart. After performing submit, all the entered values of 'rowYAxis' input field is changed to first value in the table. Why is this happening? What is wrong in data binding?

P.S: I am new to angular, any response or solution would help a lot.!

The HTML Form contents are as follows,

```
<div class="form-group"  >
    <table class="table border">
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of chartData ; let i = index;">
             <td><input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="chartData[i].xAxis" formControlName="rowxAxis" name="{{row.xAxis}}" placeholder="X axis Value" /></td>
             <td><input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="chartData[i].yAxis" formControlName="rowyAxis" name="{{row.yAxis}}" placeholder="Y axis Value" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The ngOnInit function contents are as shown below,

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.onLoadConfigInformation();
    this.chartForm = new FormGroup({
      xAxisHeader: new FormControl(),
      yAxisHeader: new FormControl(),
      rowxAxis: this.fb.control({value: 'rowXaxis'}),
      rowyAxis: this.fb.control({value: 'rowYaxis'})
   });
   this.fileUpload = new FormGroup({
    folderName: new FormControl()
 });
    this.chartData = [{"xAxis":"", "yAxis":0}];
}
```

Create chart function sets the values to another variable,

```
createChart(){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.chartData.length; i++) {
      this.chartData[i].yAxis = Number(this.chartData[i].yAxis);
    }
    this.chartDataSource = this.chartData;
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.chartData));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using formControl than you not need to use ngModel or name property .

you can get value from `formGroup`:

```
createChart(){
   const FormValue = this.chartForm.value;
   formValue.rowxAxis = +   formValue.rowxAxis;
   formValue.rowyAxis = +   formValue.rowyAxis; 
   // you can use value as per your requirement than reset the form,
   this.chartForm.reset();
}
```